# How do you get a Block in minecraft on ps4 without going to go in your inventory in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I was playing Minecraft on ps4 when I noticed you can't copy blocks. How can you copy blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but it is only implemented in java edition and with the help of command blocks bedrock edition too